# Can a Wifi device be made to output a continuous 2.4 GHz wave?

Tags: wifi, microwave

I wanted to do some energy harvesting experiments involving wifi-frequency microwaves and wanted to see if there was a way to make a Wifi-enabled microcontroller devboard (something like the esp32) output a continuous, "blank" (no data) ~2.4 GHz (one of the channels) signal. I assume Wifi is similar to bluetooth with brief, intermittent transmissions. I'm not sure if this is even possible but assumed it was worth an ask.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really all that similar. Yes, as anything with any bandwidth in ISM band, it's bursty, but it doesn't hop like bluetooth, and its individual on time is far far longer than a single bluetooth hop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially any data radio's hardware is capable of doing this, as emitting a continuous carrier wave is one of the key parts of regulatory acceptance testing.

*How* you do it is not always a public feature, sometimes it requires an alternate firmware you have to obtain from the silicon manufacturer.

If you just need a low power carrier, the RF registers of the nRF24 series are very well documented and can be easily controlled from an MCU of choice with firmware you can quickly write from scratch.  This may be easier than trying to get a more complex wifi-type radio to do it.